# How to move WPF DataGrid Rows using Drag and Drop?

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I followed an example from http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop
I am pretty sure I copied all the codes yet strangely I can't see any Drag and Drop effects?

Anyone please have a look at the copied codes?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e3hgg8kbfjqx21d/AADyTdHQsg1BOcPGePbBnt1ga?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I analyzed your code and found the issue.

the issue occurs because you've accidently used `System.Windows.Controls` instead of `Microsoft.Windows.Controls` for the reference of `DataGridRow` used in the following line

```cs
var row = UIHelpers.TryFindFromPoint<DataGridRow>((UIElement)sender, e.GetPosition(shareGrid));
```

so modify the following reference in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```cs
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

to

```cs
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;
```

Let me know if this helps